# Spark sql, choropleth, folium and geodata from zip: how to make tooltips

Tags: pyspark, tooltip, folium, choropleth

I'm trying to use Choropleth and Folium library with this data:

https://www.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page

1. NYC yellow taxi data in parquet format from  https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2019-12.parquet
2. NYC taxi zones from https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/misc/taxi_zones.zip   (.shp file included )

I am running the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

df_Y_dec_2019 = spark.read.parquet(params['y_dec_2019'])
df_Y_dec_2019.createOrReplaceTempView("ParquetTable")

  # PULocationID is the id of taxi zone where pickup was made
req_str = "select PULocationID, AVG(total_amount) as avg_amount from ParquetTable where passenger_count=2 group by PULocationID" 
parkSQL = spark.sql(req_str)
parkSQL = parkSQL.toPandas()

urllib.request.urlretrieve(params['taxi_zones_url'], params['taxi_zones'])
zipfile = "zip://" + params['taxi_zones']        
zones_sh_file = gpd.read_file(zipfile)

m = folium.Map(location=[40.7594,-73.9549], zoom_start=10, width=900, height=500)
cp = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = zones_sh_file['geometry'],
    name = 'choropleth',
    data = parkSQL,
    columns=['PULocationID', 'avg_amount'],
    key_on = 'feature.id',
    fill_color = 'YlGnBu',
    legend_name='Zones and avg amount for 2 persons'
).add_to(m)
m
```

It's ok for picture, but I cannot create a **tooltips** with **name of zones** (which are in geodata and can be found by LocationID and PULocationID in data) **and avg_amount**.
What should I do?

P.s.
Initial parquet data

```
df_Y_dec_2019.printSchema()
root
 |-- VendorID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tpep_pickup_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- tpep_dropoff_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- passenger_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- trip_distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- RatecodeID: double (nullable = true)
 |-- store_and_fwd_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PULocationID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- DOLocationID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- payment_type: long (nullable = true)
 |-- fare_amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- extra: double (nullable = true)
 |-- mta_tax: double (nullable = true)
 |-- tip_amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- tolls_amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- improvement_surcharge: double (nullable = true)
 |-- total_amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- congestion_surcharge: double (nullable = true)
 |-- airport_fee: integer (nullable = true)
```

parkSQL.show()

```
+------------+------------------+
|PULocationID|        avg_amount|
+------------+------------------+
|          29| 26.27307692307693|
|          26|17.360000000000003|
|          65| 21.28732895969984|
|         191| 48.40041666666665|
|         222|              22.3|
|         243|24.372914285714344|
|          54|            25.665|
|          19|23.248181818181823|
|         113|17.111078506095183|
|         112|18.775625000000062|
|         155| 58.00758620689653|
|         167|24.853333333333318|
|         237| 15.33061538462015|
|         241|36.212972972972956|
|         198|20.841176470588238|
|          22|21.754666666666672|
|         130| 62.28692640692642|
|         196|43.650555555555634|
|           7| 14.95269406392672|
|          77|20.300000000000004|
+------------+------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

geodata:

```
print(zones_sh_file)
     OBJECTID  Shape_Leng  Shape_Area                     zone  LocationID  \
0           1    0.116357    0.000782           Newark Airport           1   
1           2    0.433470    0.004866              Jamaica Bay           2   
2           3    0.084341    0.000314  Allerton/Pelham Gardens           3   
3           4    0.043567    0.000112            Alphabet City           4   
4           5    0.092146    0.000498            Arden Heights           5   
..        ...         ...         ...                      ...         ...   
258       259    0.126750    0.000395       Woodlawn/Wakefield         259   
259       260    0.133514    0.000422                 Woodside         260   
260       261    0.027120    0.000034       World Trade Center         261   
261       262    0.049064    0.000122           Yorkville East         262   
262       263    0.037017    0.000066           Yorkville West         263   

           borough                                           geometry  
0              EWR  POLYGON ((933100.918 192536.086, 933091.011 19...  
1           Queens  MULTIPOLYGON (((1033269.244 172126.008, 103343...  
2            Bronx  POLYGON ((1026308.770 256767.698, 1026495.593 ...  
3        Manhattan  POLYGON ((992073.467 203714.076, 992068.667 20...  
4    Staten Island  POLYGON ((935843.310 144283.336, 936046.565 14...  
..             ...                                                ...  
258          Bronx  POLYGON ((1025414.782 270986.139, 1025138.624 ...  
259         Queens  POLYGON ((1011466.966 216463.005, 1011545.889 ...  
260      Manhattan  POLYGON ((980555.204 196138.486, 980570.792 19...  
261      Manhattan  MULTIPOLYGON (((999804.795 224498.527, 999824....  
262      Manhattan  POLYGON ((997493.323 220912.386, 997355.264 22...  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hujjY.jpg
```